# Suddenly can't open password protected .docx files in Word desktop app and web app

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, docx

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xgi.png)

File is stored in OneDrive. I created it before. It's not stored in SharePoint. Other docx files without password protection from Word open successfully.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: One line of text and a photo do not a coherent and complete question make.

Comment: Where does this file stored? Did this file created by yourself? If this file is stored on SharePoint, it may be realted to eidt permission, please refer to "["Sorry, this document can't be opened for editing" error creating a document in Office Web Apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/quot-sorry-this-document-can-t-be-opened-for-editing-quot-error/ba-p/1431291)".

Comment: @music2myear Why are you assuming that I have other useful information to share but refuse to share it?

Comment: @Emily File is stored in OneDrive. I created it before. It's not stored in SharePoint.

Comment: @alex1923 Thanks for your information, please go to OneDrive online, right click this file > Preview, check whether you may download this file and open it successfully. If you could download it, I suggest you rename it, then upload back to OneDrive.

Comment: @Emily Tried everything you said, but I still can't open the file. Another information about my situation is that other .docx files without password protection form Word open successfully.